# js in default/files causes extreme slowdown of website

Tags: 7, theming, database, javascript, caching

for the past week my website is plagued with over 4000ms hanging upon entering, more so at sometimes. After using firefox's performance monitor, I pinpointed it to several lines of code in a js file under /sites/default/files/js.
  Here is a snippet of the js:

```
(function(e,t){var n,r,i=typeof t,o=e.location,a=e.document,s=a.documentElement,l=e.jQuery,u=e.$,c={},p=[],f="1.10.2",d=p.concat,h=p.push,g=p.slice,m=p.indexOf,y=c.toString,v=c.hasOwnProperty,b=f.trim,x=function(e,t){return new x.fn.init(e,t,r)},w=/[+-]?(?:\d*\.|)\d+(?:[eE][+-]?\d+|)/.source,T=/\S+/g,C=/^[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+|[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+$/g,N=/^(?:\s*(<[\w\W]+>)[^>]*|#([\w-]*))$/,k=/^<(\w+)\s*\/?>(?:<\/\1>|)$/,E=/^[\],:{}\s]*$/,S=/(?:^|:|,)(?:\s*\[)+/g,A=/\\(?:["\\\/bfnrt]|u[\da-fA-F]{4})/g,j=/"[^"\\\r\n]*"|true|false|null|-?(?:\d+\.|)\d+(?:[eE][+-]?\d+|)/g,D=/^-ms-/,L=/-([\da-z])/gi,H=function(e,t){return t.toUpperCase()},q=function(e){(a.addEventListener||"load"===e.type||"complete"===a.readyState)&&(_(),x.ready())},_=function(){a.addEventListener?(a.removeEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",q,!1),e.removeEventListener("load",q,!1)):(a.detachEvent("onreadystatechange",q),e.detachEvent("onload",q))};x.fn=x.prototype={jquery:f,constructor:x,init:function(e,n,r){var i,o;if(!e)return this;if("string"==typeof e){if(i="<"===e.charAt(0)&&">"===e.charAt(e.length-1)&&e.length>=3?[null,e,null]:N.exec(e),!i||!i[1]&&n)return!n||n.jquery?(n||r).find(e):this.constructor(n).find(e);if(i[1]){if(n=n instanceof x?n[0]:n,x.merge(this,x.parseHTML(i[1],n&&n.nodeType?n.ownerDocument||n:a,!0)),k.test(i[1])&&x.isPlainObject(n))for(i in n)x.isFunction(this[i])?this[i](n[i]):this.attr(i,n[i]);return this}if(o=a.getElementById(i[2]),o&&o.parentNode){if(o.id!==i[2])return r.find(e);this.length=1,this[0]=o}return this.context=a,this.selector=e,this}return e.nodeType?(this.context=this[0]=e,this.length=1,this):x.isFunction(e)?r.ready(e):(e.selector!==t&&(this.selector=e.selector,this.context=e.context),x.makeArray(e,this))},selector:"",length:0,toArray:function(){return g.call(this)},get:function(e){return null==e?this.toArray():0>e?this[this.length+e]:this[e]},pushStack:function(e){var t=x.merge(this.constructor(),e);return t.prevObject=this,t.context=this.context,t},each:function(e,t){return x.each(this,e,t)},ready:function(e){return x.ready.promise().done(e),this},slice:function(){return this.pushStack(g.apply(this,arguments))},first:function(){return this.eq(0)},last:function(){return this.eq(-1)},eq:function(e){var t=this.length,n=+e+(0>e?t:0);return this.pushStack(n>=0&&t>n?[this[n]]:[])},map:function(e){return this.pushStack(x.map(this,function(t,n){return e.call(t,n,t)}))},end:function(){return this.prevObject||this.constructor(null)},push:h,sort:[].sort,splice:[].splice},x.fn.init.prototype=x.fn,x.extend=x.fn.extend=function(){var e,n,r,i,o,a,s=arguments[0]||{},l=1,u=arguments.length,c=!1;for("boolean"==typeof s&&(c=s,s=arguments[1]||{},l=2),"object"==typeof s||x.isFunction(s)||(s={}),u===l&&(s=this,--l);u>l;l++)if(null!=(o=arguments[l]))for(i in o)e=s[i],r=o[i],s!==r&&(c&&r&&(x.isPlainObject(r)||(n=x.isArray(r)))?(n?(n=!1,a=e&&x.isArray(e)?e:[]):a=e&&x.isPlainObject(e)?e:{},s[i]=x.extend(c,a,r)):r!==t&&(s[i]=r));return s},x.extend({expando:"jQuery"+(f+Math.random()).replace(/\D/g,""),noConflict:function(t){return e.$===x&&(e.$=u),t&&e.jQuery===x&&(e.jQuery=l),x},isReady:!1,readyWait:1,holdReady:function(e){e?x.readyWait++:x.ready(!0)},ready:function(e){if(e===!0?!--x.readyWait:!x.isReady){if(!a.body)return setTimeout(x.ready);x.isReady=!0,e!==!0&&--x.readyWait>0||(n.resolveWith(a,[x]),x.fn.trigger&&x(a).trigger("ready").off("ready"))}},isFunction:function(e){return"function"===x.type(e)},isArray:Array.isArray||function(e){return"array"===x.type(e)},isWindow:function(e){return null!=e&&e==e.window},isNumeric:function(e){return!isNaN(parseFloat(e))&&isFinite(e)},type:function(e){return null==e?e+"":"object"==typeof e||"function"==typeof e?c[y.call(e)]||"object":typeof e},isPlainObject:function(e){var n;if(!e||"object"!==x.type(e)||e.nodeType||x.isWindow(e))return!1;try{if(e.constructor&&!v.call(e,"constructor")&&!v.call(e.constructor.prototype,"isPrototypeOf"))return!1}catch(r){return!1}if(x.support.ownLast)for(n in e)return v.call(e,n);for(n in e);return n===t||v.call(e,n)},isEmptyObject:function(e){var t;for(t in e)return!1;return!0},error:function(e){throw Error(e)},parseHTML:function(e,t,n){if(!e||"string"!=typeof e)return null;"boolean"==typeof t&&(n=t,t=!1),t=t||a;var r=k.exec(e),i=!n&&[];return r?[t.createElement(r[1])]:(r=x.buildFragment([e],t,i),i&&x(i).remove(),x.merge([],r.childNodes))},parseJSON:function(n){return e.JSON&&e.JSON.parse?e.JSON.parse(n):null===n?n:"string"==typeof n&&(n=x.trim(n),n&&E.test(n.replace(A,"@").replace(j,"]").replace(S,"")))?Function("return "+n)():(x.error("Invalid JSON: "+n),t)},parseXML:function(n){var r,i;if(!n||"string"!=typeof n)return null;try{e.DOMParser?(i=new DOMParser,r=i.parseFromString(n,"text/xml")):(r=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM"),r.async="false",r.loadXML(n))}catch(o){r=t}return r&&r.documentElement&&!r.getElementsByTagName("parsererror").length||x.error("Invalid XML: "+n),r},noop:function(){},globalEval:function(t){t&&x.trim(t)&&(e.execScript||function(t){e.eval.call(e,t)})(t)},camelCase:function(e){return e.replace(D,"ms-").replace(L,H)},nodeName:function(e,t){return e.nodeName&&e.nodeName.toLowerCase()===t.toLowerCase()},each:function(e,t,n){var r,i=0,o=e.length,a=M(e);if(n){if(a){for(;o>i;i++)if(r=t.apply(e[i],n),r===!1)break}else for(i in e)if(r=t.apply(e[i],n),r===!1)break}else if(a){for(;o>i;i++)if(r=t.call(e[i],i,e[i]),r===!1)break}else for(i in e)if(r=t.call(e[i],i,e[i]),r===!1)break;return e},trim:b&&!b.call("\ufeff\u00a0")?function(e){return null==e?"":b.call(e)}:function(e){return null==e?"":(e+"").replace(C,"")},makeArray:function(e,t){var n=t||[];return null!=e&&(M(Object(e))?x.merge(n,"string"==typeof e?[e]:e):h.call(n,e)),n},inArray:function(e,t,n){var r;if(t){if(m)return m.call(t,e,n);for(r=t.length,n=n?0>n?Math.max(0,r+n):n:0;r>n;n++)if(n in t&&t[n]===e)return n}return-1},merge:function(e,n){var r=n.length,i=e.length,o=0;if("number"==typeof r)for(;r>o;o++)e[i++]=n[o];else while(n[o]!==t)e[i++]=n[o++];return e.length=i,e},grep:function(e,t,n){var r,i=[],o=0,a=e.length;for(n=!!n;a>o;o++)r=!!t(e[o],o),n!==r&&i.push(e[o]);return i},map:function(e,t,n){var r,i=0,o=e.length,a=M(e),s=[];if(a)for(;o>i;i++)r=t(e[i],i,n),null!=r&&(s[s.length]=r);else for(i in e)r=t(e[i],i,n),null!=r&&(s[s.length]=r);return d.apply([],s)},guid:1,proxy:function(e,n){var r,i,o;return"string"==typeof n&&(o=e[n],n=e,e=o),x.isFunction(e)?(r=g.call(arguments,2),i=function(){return e.apply(n||this,r.concat(g.call(arguments)))},i.guid=e.guid=e.guid||x.guid++,i):t},access:function(e,n,r,i,o,a,s){var l=0,u=e.length,c=null==r;if("object"===x.type(r)){o=!0;for(l in r)x.access(e,n,l,r[l],!0,a,s)}else if(i!==t&&(o=!0,x.isFunction(i)||(s=!0),c&&(s?(n.call(e,i),n=null):(c=n,n=function(e,t,n){return c.call(x(e),n)})),n))for(;u>l;l++)n(e[l],r,s?i:i.call(e[l],l,n(e[l],r)));return o?e:c?n.call(e):u?n(e[0],r):a},now:function(){return(new Date).getTime()},swap:function(e,t,n,r){var i,o,a={};for(o in t)a[o]=e.style[o],e.style[o]=t[o];i=n.apply(e,r||[]);for(o in t)e.style[o]=a[o];return i}}),x.ready.promise=function(t){if(!n)if(n=x.Deferred(),"complete"===a.readyState)setTimeout(x.ready);else if(a.addEventListener)a.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",q,!1),e.addEventListener("load",q,!1);else{a.attachEvent("onreadystatechange",q),e.attachEvent("onload",q);var r=!1;try{r=null==e.frameElement&&a.documentElement}catch(i){}r&&r.doScroll&&function o(){if(!x.isReady){try{r.doScroll("left")}catch(e){return setTimeout(o,50)}_(),x.ready()}}()}return n.promise(t)},x.each("Boolean Number String Function Array Date RegExp Object Error".split(" "),function(e,t){c["[object "+t+"]"]=t.toLowerCase()});function M(e){var t=e.length,n=x.type(e);return x.isWindow(e)?!1:1===e.nodeType&&t?!0:"array"===n||"function"!==n&&(0===t||"number"==typeof t&&t>0&&t-1 in e)}r=x(a),function(e,t){var n,r,i,o,a,s,l,u,c,p,f,d,h,g,m,y,v,b="sizzle"+-new Date,w=e.document,T=0,C=0,N=st(),k=st(),E=st(),S=!1,A=function(e,t){return e===t?(S=!0,0):0},j=typeof t,D=1<<31,L={}.hasOwnProperty,H=[],q=H.pop,_=H.push,M=H.push,O=H.slice,F=H.indexOf||function(e){var t=0,n=this.length;for(;n>t;t++)if(this[t]===e)return t;return-1},B="checked|selected|async|autofocus|autoplay|controls|defer|disabled|hidden|ismap|loop|multiple|open|readonly|required|scoped",P="[\\x20\\t\\r\\n\\f]",R="(?:\\\\.|[\\w-]|[^\\x00-\\xa0])+",W=R.replace("w","w#"),$="\\["+P+"*("+R+")"+P+"*(?:([*^$|!~]?=)"+P+"*(?:(['\"])((?:\\\\.|[^\\\\])*?)\\3|("+W+")|)|)"+P+"*\\]",I=":("+R+")(?:\\(((['\"])((?:\\\\.|[^\\\\])*?)\\3|((?:\\\\.|[^\\\\()[\\]]|"+$.replace(3,8)+")*)|.*)\\)|)",z=RegExp("^"+P+"+|((?:^|[^\\\\])(?:\\\\.)*)"+P+"+$","g"),X=RegExp("^"+P+"*,"+P+"*"),U=RegExp("^"+P+"*([>+~]|"+P+")"+P+"*"),V=RegExp(P+"*[+~]"),Y=RegExp("="+P+"*([^\\]'\"]*)"+P+"*\\]","g"),J=RegExp(I),G=RegExp("^"+W+"$"),Q={ID:RegExp("^#("+R+")"),CLASS:RegExp("^\\.("+R+")"),TAG:RegExp("^("+R.replace("w","w*")+")"),ATTR:RegExp("^"+$),PSEUDO:RegExp("^"+I),CHILD:RegExp("^:(only|first|last|nth|nth-last)-(child|of-type)(?:\\("+P+"*(even|odd|(([+-]|)(\\d*)n|)"+P+"*(?:([+-]|)"+P+"*(\\d+)|))"+P+"*\\)|)","i"),bool:RegExp("^(?:"+B+")$","i"),needsContext:RegExp("^"+P+"*[>+~]|:(even|odd|eq|gt|lt|nth|first|last)(?:\\("+P+"*((?:-\\d)?\\d*)"+P+"*\\)|)(?=[^-]|$)","i")},K=/^[^{]+\{\s*\[native \w/,Z=/^(?:#([\w-]+)|(\w+)|\.([\w-]+))$/,et=/^(?:input|select|textarea|button)$/i,tt=/^h\d$/i,nt=/'|\\/g,rt=RegExp("\\\\([\\da-f]{1,6}"+P+"?|("+P+")|.)","ig"),it=function(e,t,n){var r="0x"+t-65536;return r!==r||n?t:0>r?String.fromCharCode(r+65536):String.fromCharCode(55296|r>>10,56320|1023&r)};try{M.apply(H=O.call(w.childNodes),w.childNodes),H[w.childNodes.length].nodeType}catch(ot){M={apply:H.length?function(e,t){_.apply(e,O.call(t))}:function(e,t){var n=e.length,r=0;while(e[n++]=t[r++]);e.length=n-1}}}function at(e,t,n,i){var o,a,s,l,u,c,d,m,y,x;if((t?t.ownerDocument||t:w)!==f&&p(t),t=t||f,n=n||[],!e||"string"!=typeof e)return n;if(1!==(l=t.nodeType)&&9!==l)return[];if(h&&!i){if(o=Z.exec(e))if(s=o[1]){if(9===l){if(a=t.getElementById(s),!a||!a.parentNode)return n;if(a.id===s)return n.push(a),n}else if(t.ownerDocument&&(a=t.ownerDocument.getElementById(s))&&v(t,a)&&a.id===s)return n.push(a),n}else{if(o[2])return M.apply(n,t.getElementsByTagName(e)),n;if((s=o[3])&&r.getElementsByClassName&&t.getElementsByClassName)return M.apply(n,t.getElementsByClassName(s)),n}if(r.qsa&&(!g||!g.test(e))){if(m=d=b,y=t,x=9===l&&e,1===l&&"object"!==t.nodeName.toLowerCase()){c=mt(e),(d=t.getAttribute("id"))?m=d.replace(nt,"\\$&"):t.setAttribute("id",m),m="[id='"+m+"'] ",u=c.length;while(u--)c[u]=m+yt(c[u]);y=V.test(e)&&t.parentNode||t,x=c.join(",")}if(x)try{return M.apply(n,y.querySelectorAll(x)),n}catch(T){}finally{d||t.removeAttribute("id")}}}return kt(e.replace(z,"$1"),t,n,i)}function st(){var e=[];function t(n,r){return e.push(n+=" ")>o.cacheLength&&delete t[e.shift()],t[n]=r}return t}function lt(e){return e[b]=!0,e}function ut(e){var t=f.createElement("div");try{return!!e(t)}catch(n){return!1}finally{t.parentNode&&t.parentNode.removeChild(t),t=null}}function ct(e,t){var n=e.split("|"),r=e.length;while(r--)o.attrHandle[n[r]]=t}function pt(e,t){var n=t&&e,r=n&&1===e.nodeType&&1===t.nodeType&&(~t.sourceIndex||D)-(~e.sourceIndex||D);if(r)return r;if(n)while(n=n.nextSibling)if(n===t)return-1;return e?1:-1}function ft(e){return function(t){var n=t.nodeName.toLowerCase();return"input"===n&&t.type===e}}function dt(e){return function(t){var n=t.nodeName.toLowerCase();return("input"===n||"button"===n)&&t.type===e}}function ht(e){return lt(function(t){return t=+t,lt(function(n,r){var i,o=e([],n.length,t),a=o.length;while(a--)n[i=o[a]]&&(n[i]=!(r[i]=n[i]))})})}s=at.isXML=function(e){var t=e&&(e.ownerDocument||e).documentElement;return t?"HTML"!==t.nodeName:!1},r=at.support={},p=at.setDocument=function(e){var n=e?e.ownerDocument||e:w,i=n.defaultView;return n!==f&&9===n.nodeType&&n.documentElement?(f=n,d=n.documentElement,h=!s(n),i&&i.attachEvent&&i!==i.top&&i.attachEvent("onbeforeunload",function(){p()}),r.attributes=ut(function(e){return e.className="i",!e.getAttribute("className")}),r.getElementsByTagName=ut(function(e){return e.appendChild(n.createComment("")),!e.getElementsByTagName("*").length}),r.getElementsByClassName=ut(function(e){return e.innerHTML="<div class='a'></div><div class='a i'></div>",e.firstChild.className="i",2===e.getElementsByClassName("i").length}),r.getById=ut(function(e){return d.appendChild(e).id=b,!n.getElementsByName||!n.getElementsByName(b).length}),r.getById?(o.find.ID=function(e,t){if(typeof t.getElementById!==j&&h){var n=t.getElementById(e);return n&&n.parentNode?[n]:[]}},o.filter.ID=function(e){var t=e.replace(rt,it);return function(e){return e.getAttribute("id")===t}}):(delete o.find.ID,o.filter.ID=function(e){var t=e.replace(rt,it);return function(e){var n=typeof e.getAttributeNode!==j&&e.getAttributeNode("id");return n&&n.value===t}}),o.find.TAG=r.getElementsByTagName?function(e,n){return typeof n.getElementsByTagName!==j?n.getElementsByTagName(e):t}:function(e,t){var n,r=[],i=0,o=t.getElementsByTagName(e);if("*"===e){while(n=o[i++])1===n.nodeType&&r.push(n);return r}return o},o.find.CLASS=r.getElementsByClassName&&function(e,n){return typeof n.getElementsByClassName!==j&&h?n.getElementsByClassName(e):t},m=[],g=[],(r.qsa=K.test(n.querySelectorAll))&&(ut(function(e){e.innerHTML="<select><option selected=''></option></select>",e.querySelectorAll("[selected]").length||g.push("\\["+P+"*(?:value|"+B+")"),e.querySelectorAll(":checked").length||g.push(":checked")}),ut(function(e){var t=n.createElement("input");t.setAttribute("type","hidden"),e.appendChild(t).setAttribute("t",""),e.querySelectorAll("[t^='']").length&&g.push("[*^$]="+P+"*(?:''|\"\")"),e.querySelectorAll(":enabled").length||g.push(":enabled",":disabled"),e.querySelectorAll("*,:x"),g.push(",.*:")})),(r.matchesSelector=K.test(y=d.webkitMatchesSelector||d.mozMatchesSelector||d.oMatchesSelector||d.msMatchesSelector))&&ut(function(e)....
```

It continues on like that for dozens of more lines, and it is impossible for me to fit it all here. I know this is an autogenerated code issue, but do not know where I should start looking.

Can anyone pinpoint me to the correct area to look at? Thanks.
Aaron

Comment: You will probably have better luck debugging if you disable js/css aggregation, which is going to obfuscate the library (somewhat) that may be causing this issue on your site. There is no way to answer this question because it is unclear from what you posted what the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal aggregates all of the javascript files added by any modules and themes. So that's why its all 1 big file.

You could turn off the JS aggregation by going to "Configuration > development > performance" and unticking the JS option.

That will allow you to narrow down the actual script that might be slowing you down. It's almost certainly not something from Drupal core itself and more likely to be something custom youve done in a theme or a module you've enabled

Comment: Thank you!  I was able to point to the JQuery update module, which has a major hanging issue currently. Cheers.